# Is there any method to mount a block of memory as a filesystem in linux?

Tags: kernel, filesystems, memory

I have a question,in linux, is there any method to mount a block of memory as a filesystem?
For example, in X86 architecture, when power on, I reserve a  block of memory about 8
Mbytes, and then when linux startup, I mount this block of memory as a filesystem and then read and write file to the file system ? What will be the fs type?

Comment: You can boot up with ramdisk=size, and mkfs & mount /dev/ramdiskN; or boot up with memmap=size!offset, and mkfs & mount /dev/pmemN. But what is your specific use case?

Answer (score 4):

[ramfs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)

(bet you'd never have guessed that). You might also want to have a look at [tmpfs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/) and overlay filesystems (latter provides a mechanism for cloning the filesystem at power up/down - see Puppy Linux)